# Dagger2 Qualifier not working with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a simple class as below

```
class MainString(val msg: String)
```

I want to inject with different argument to it, so I use the `@Named` Qualifier as per the guide shown in https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide

With that my AppModule has

```
@Provides @Named("Two")
fun provideTwoMainString(): MainString {
    return MainString("Two")
}

@Provides @Named("One")
fun provideOneMainString(): MainString {
    return MainString("One")
}
```

And in my MainActivity, I just call

```
@Inject @Named("One")
lateinit var stringOne: MainString

@Inject @Named("Two")
lateinit var stringTwo: MainString
```

However, when I compile, it complains

```
Error:(11, 1) error: com.elyeproj.demo_dagger_scope.MainString cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
```

It seems to want me to provide another Provider without the qualifier. So if I add the below, all will compiles. But it is not of used to me, as I want to have different argument injection.

```
@Provides
fun provideMainString(): MainString {
    return MainString("Solo")
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Annotation work slightly different on kotlin. look [this doc](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

You have to annotate the field as:

```
@Inject @field:Named("Two")
lateinit var stringOne: MainString
```

Answer (score 10):

If you add the following to your qualifier annotation:

```
@Target(FIELD, VALUE_PARAMETER, FUNCTION, PROPERTY_GETTER, PROPERTY_SETTER)
```

then you won't have to add "field:"

For example, with:

```
  @Qualifier
  @Retention(RUNTIME)
  @Target(FIELD, VALUE_PARAMETER, FUNCTION, PROPERTY_GETTER, PROPERTY_SETTER)
  annotation class One
```

you can inject as follows:

```
  @Inject @One lateinit var stringOne: String
```

Unfortunately `@Named` doesn't specify the `@Target(..)`, so just create your own annotations. `@Named` is a bad idea anyway, since it's using string literals.

Answer (score 4):

1) If you are using a qualifier like following, here 'OmdbService'

```
@Qualifier
public annotation class OmdbService
```

Then use

```
@Inject  @field:OmdbService lateinit var retrofitOmdbService: Retrofit
```

2) If are using a named provider like following, here 'orangeservice_retrofit'

```
@Provides
    @OrangeApplicationScope
    @Named("orangeservice_retrofit")
    fun retrofit(okHttpClient :OkHttpClient, gson : Gson, c :Context): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(c.getString(R.string.base_url))
                .build()
}
```

Then use

```
@Inject @field:Named("orangeservice_retrofit") lateinit var retrofitOrangeService: Retrofit
```