# @Named Annotation is not working in Activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to use the field injection into activity using dagger2. Whenever I tried to use

```
@Inject
@Named("lib_token")
lateinit var injectedLibToken: String
```

It says

```
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.myapp.MApplication> {
                ^
      java.lang.String is injected at
          com.myapp.activities.PaymentActivity.injectedLibToken
      com.myapp.activities.PaymentActivity is injected at
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AppModule::class,

        AndroidInjectionModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MCPAApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    override fun inject(application: MCPAApplication)

}
```

AppModule.kt

```
@Module(includes = [AppModule.Provider::class, ConstantModule::class])
class AppModule {

    @Module
    object Provider {

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        @Singleton
        fun providesSharePreference(context: Context) = SharePrefUtils(context)
    }
}
```

ConstantModule.kt

```
@Module
object ConstantModule {

    init {
        System.loadLibrary("keys")
    }

    external fun getBaseURL(): String?

    external fun getAppToken(): String?

    external fun getAppClientSecret(): String?

    external fun getDynamicDomain(): String?

    external fun getDynamicLink(): String?

    external fun getLibToken(): String?

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Named("socket_url")
    fun providesURL() = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("client_id")
    fun providesClientID(): String = "1"


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("lib_token")
    fun providesLibToken(): String {
        return getLibToken()!!
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("token")
    fun providesToken(): String = getAppToken()!!


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("dynamic_prefix")
    fun providesDynamicLinkPrefix(): String = getDynamicLink()!!


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("dynamic_domain")
    fun providesDynamicLinkDomain(): String = getDynamicDomain()!!


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("client_secret")
    fun providesClientSecret(): String = getAppClientSecret()!!


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("api_key")
    fun providesApiKey(): String = "xxx"


    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @Named("base_url")
    fun providesBaseUrl(): String = getBaseURL()!!
}
```

The key can be injected at the constructor of the repositories. But When I tried to inject it at the activity, the above error keeps showing. Can anyone point out me where I did wrong?

Comment: you have to tell your appcomponent to inject into the activity https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android#injecting-activities

Comment: I did. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which Dagger version are you using?

Comment: 2.21 @Nitrodon.

Comment: Prior to version 2.25.2, you need to use the `field:` use-site target for qualifier annotations on Kotlin properties.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564926/dagger2-qualifier-not-working-with-kotlin